# Box.com File Uploading in php

Tags: php, box-api

I am integrating Box.com Api to upload files from my website.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="boxap"  /><input type="submit" name="sub" />
</form>
<?php 
    $tmpfile = $_FILES['boxap']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = basename($_FILES['boxap']['name']);

    $_POST['boxap'] = '@'.$tmpfile;

    $upload_url = 'https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/token/folderid';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $response;
?>
```

I have token but where can I get folder id? Also, is the method ok I upload file to box.com
Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Where can I get folder id?**

By hitting the [folder API endpoint](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#folder-object) to grab the folder details. By passing `FOLDER_ID` as `0`, you will get your root folder, so that you can traverse through the children to find your folder. These ids won't change, so you can store these locally.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

**Also, is the method ok I upload file to box.com**

Sure, it's ok in terms of it will post to box.com. I'm unsure what you're asking, but using [cURL](http://php.net/curl) is fine. It's used [throughout their documentation](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#upload-a-file). Though, you seem to be missing some multipart POST data;

- `attributes`

  - `name` - name of the file
  - `parent` - folder object being uploaded into

    - `id` - child of parent. Designates fold_id of parent object. Use 0 for the root folder.
- `file`

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST \
  -F attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}' \
  -F file=@myfile.jpg
```

Comment: Just to add to this, it appears in the initial post that you're attempting to use the V1 version of the API which was deprecated in Dec 2013. [Deprecation Article](https://www.box.com/blog/start-migrating-to-v2-of-the-content-api-deprecating-v1-in-december/)

Comment: Thanks Paul , but I am totally new to this. I only have one file of coding i have pasted above. What and where should i download if anything else needed.